# No vertices at face intersections?

Tags: objects, vertices, faces

I just made an object (trapezium form) and then I duplicate it 3 times to make it square as the base of my construction, and joined all 4 of it so i can edit it at the same time. The problem is that I don't have any vertices in every intersection like the picture here, so how to fix this?
[image: object in edit mode]

Comment: in the image above you've activated "face select" mode, so it's not possible to see (any) vertices. Switch to "vertex select" mode to see them. I'm pretty sure _there are_ vertices where you are looking for them. Anyway, as face centers are showing in the image above, your current topology has some issues (face centers should better be only at... face centers), fwiw.

Comment: alright, thnks anyway, I'm new to this, it's still none vertext after swithing mode, an yes I don't really know about the topologi Lol, still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Go into Edit mode and hit <kbd>P</kbd> (Separate) > By Loose Parts. This will separate the pieces of your object.
- Pick one of the objects, for example the first one. Add 3 Boolean modifiers to it.
- Switch the Operation to Union on all the modifiers.
- Set each modifier's Object to be one of the other pieces.
- If you get strange results in wireframe mode, switch the Solvers to Carve instead of BMesh.
- Hit Apply on each modifier, and  delete the other pieces. You don't need them anymore.

Note that this **may destroy your topology**. It will keep the shape, but the arrangement of faces may be different.

Comment: Hey, thans man, it works as what I want,

yeah, it's ok for me if it ruins the topologi of my object, since I just want to view the final result, so no need to worry about it,

thnks for the help :)

Comment: You're quite welcome! Glad I could help.